# Safari on PC, height of some of divs are stretched excessively

Tags: html, css, safari

I have this test site http://test-donkeyondafish.work/ezo/index.html

When I open on Safari, some of the div elements height are all stretched.

1. Blue button (I have the same button placed in 2 other locations and they all have the same issue.
2. Weekly schedule

I don't know why this is happening.  Firefox, Chrome, Safari on mobile, they all seem to work fine.

Any help would be appreciated!

I've searched for the same case, but no luck.  If I specify the height like 100px, it works.

Comment: "PC" as in *Windows PC*? The last update to Safari on Windows was made in 2012. Opening that page on the latest Safari 15.4 I don't see anything particularly different to what Firefox produces. Anyway, please add a [MCVE] into the question itself.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.